# Spring Boot application with Postgres: indexes not being used during first use

Tags: spring, postgresql

I have a Spring Boot application that is using a Postgres database. When the application is deployed I need to run a transactional operation that uploads a zip file that is used to populate the database. The application is checking for duplicate rows before inserting them (because users can upload duplicate data that should just be ignored).

The problem I am having is that the first time I upload the file, even thought the indexes are created, they are not being used when checking for the existence of a row. My theory is that this happens because the query plan is deciding not to use the index because it is checking the original statistics, which show that the tables are empty. If I upload a small zip file first, then the problem goes away because the tables now have data.

I have two questions. First, is my theory correct or is there some other reason for this behaviour? Also, if so, is there a way to force Postgres to update the query plan it uses at some predefined interval within the same transaction and can this be done using JPA? Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: So is this problem only occurring when the destination table be completely empty?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If I add a subset of the data and then add the full zip file it does perform as expected.

Comment: The reason I asked you this is because if it is really only a problem which happens with a clean slate database, then you probably aren't going to encounter this too often in production, unless you keep deploying to new customer sites all the time (or something like that).

Comment: Yes, it is not a huge problem in production. It does have an impact on our integration tests where the first step is to upload and import a huge zip file. There are simple workarounds (such as uploading a subset first) but I just wanted to know if there was a cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone runs into this issue, I'll post the solution I found. It appears my theory was correct. The queries will not use the indexes until some statistics are collected. One way to force this is to call ANALYZE after a number of rows have been written to the database. You can do this using a native query like this:

`entityManager.createNativeQuery("ANALYZE " + tbl).executeUpdate();`

You can wrap this call in a try catch and ignore any exceptions that might occur if you change the database engine. I couldn't find a way of doing this in a database-independent way but this approach works fine and now the initial upload performs as expected.